# Crystal : class warp or extension methods like CSharp

Tags: metaprogramming, crystal-lang

I exported a struct from a C library which is `Void*`

```
lib LibXXX
    alias OldStruct = Pointer(Void)
    fun foo(old : OldStruct)
end
```

And want to add some methods to `LibXXX::Old`

I know it's can only be done by a class warp in most language :

```
struct NewStruct {
    OldStruct old;
    void new_functions();
};
```

But it's really bothering that I must access field `old` explicitly. `LibXXX.foo(old.old)`

I want some transparent way keeping simple representation `LibXXX.foo(old)`, like **Inheritance** or **Extension Methods** in CSharp.

I tried :

```
struct NewStruct < LibXXX::Old
# ...
end
```

But an compilation error occured:

```
can't extend non-abstract struct Pointer(Void)
```

I believe it must could be done using Crystal. But I don't know what's the best practice, so, please.

Comment: In C you don't have inheritance, so you can't do inheritance in `lib` contexts. Second of all, inheriting from a `void*` doesn't make any sense even in C++. So i'm really not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @RX14 You're right. But I want something like Extension Methods of CSharp to add methods for an exisiting lib struct, and inheritance may be a way to do this in pure OOP. I will modify my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to have a non-lib wrapper around your object, that wraps all of the existing methods. That's then often a good place to add your new functionality too or any idiomatic abstractions.

```
lib LibPet
  alias Pet = Void*
  alias Dog = Void*

  fun make_dog : Dog
  fun bark(bar : Dog)
  fun move(pet : Pet)
  fun retreat(pet : Pet)
end

struct Dog
  def initialize
    @dog = LibPet.make_dog
  end

  def bark
    LibPet.bark(@dog)
  end

  def move
    LibPet.move(@dog)
  end

  def retreat
    LibPet.retreat(@dog)
  end

  def at_front
    move
    yield
  ensure
    retreat
  end

  def attack
    at_front { bark }
  end
end
```

Comment: Really thank you, but it's still too tedious. And memory content of the original and warpper struct are in fact the same. For other language I could accept this way but I believe there will be a better way for Crystal, as a rubyist.

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://gist.github.com/xqyww123/bc1b90cecbf46b5af15aceae503127c6), and I believe it's the way a rubyist language should use.

Comment: @XeroEssential you're inheriting from a `Pointer(Void)`. This means that every place where you use a `Pointer(Void)` in code you could get a `Dog` instead. If you add an instance variable to `Dog`, you change `sizeof(Void*)` which is definitely not what you want. This is a really weird idea that breaks a lot of assumptions and doesn't save much typing either. That's why you can't do it.

Comment: I don't get why you wouldn't add sell to the wrapper in the first place, but you could just define to_unsafe on the wrapper to return the wrapped pointer and crystal will call it for you if you pass the wrapper in a lib call

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know `to_unsafe` yet. Really thank you and this is the correct answer. Thanks, @Jonne and @RX14.